# Retrieving files using django rest Framework and postman

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, postman, backend

I am making a secure file storage system In this for the decryption process user is giving the file_id and key as an input. The program finds the file, reads it's data and decrypts it using the key and rewrites the file data of the file with the new encrypted data and return the file.
I'm using django rest framework for this.
The code for the view is given below:

```
class Decryption(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file_id = request.data.get('file_id')
        key = request.data.get('key')
        try:
            if not key:
                return Response({"error": "Key is required"}, status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            try:
                encrypted_file = EncryptedFile.objects.get(id = file_id)
            except EncryptedFile.DoesNotExist:
                return Response({'detail': "The requested File doesn't exist"}, status= status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
            
            encrypted_data = encrypted_file.file.read()

            cipher = Fernet(key)
            decrypted_data = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_data)

            encrypted_file.file.seek(0)
            #encrypted_file.file.write(decrypted_data)

            response = Response()
            response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment: filename = {encrypted_file.file_name}'
            response.write(decrypted_data)
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'details': e}, status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I was expecting a file as a result. But I got a blank screen when I made an API call using postman